# Sending ether to an account

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, ether

I am trying to send ether to an account but the transaction is sent to my contract address. Here is the code

`function send(address _account, uint amount) payable {
    _account.transfer(amount);
 }`

I mined but the balance of the account does not change. I am using geth 1.5.9

Comment: Are you using enough gas?

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an event in the function. In this way, you can later review what value `_account` held during invocation.

I'm 99.9999% certain that if the transaction got mined, then the `amount` was sent to the `_account`.  The `amount` may not have remained in the `_account` if, for example, `_account` was a contract that subsequently sent the ether to some other address through a message call (internal transaction), but without details of the transaction I can't tell you what happened.